# Is there a way to temporarily establish a SMB v1.0 share?

Tags: networking, network-shares, samba, smb

I have a client which only supports 1.0 and I want my host to have it enabled only when I use the client and doing it via Windows Features is tedious and time consuming because it requires a restart.
Is there any program or any other way to enable SMB 1.0 on demand? A VM for instance would be perfect but as far as I know there is no way to put a VM on the same LAN network as the host & client

Comment: For it to work, SMB 1.0 would have to be enabled at system level, on both the host and the client (for the latter, seems it's already on), so even if you resorted to a third-party, you'd have to go through Windows features anyway. Are you on Windows Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a VM is fine, go for it! Due to licensing concerns, it may be easier to use Linux with Samba.

> A VM for instance would be perfect but as far as I know there is no way to put a VM on the same LAN network as the host & client

This is very possible. There’s just one caveat: For this to work 100% reliably, you need a wired network connection.

Then, in your VM software, select bridged networking, instead of NAT or whatever. Depending on the network requirements you may have to manually set up IP addresses in your VM or even allow its MAC address on the network.